Swift lldb cannot print NSDictionary and NSArray
I added a Swift file to an old OC project and called the Swift method in the OC file. During the debugging process, I found that the po command of lldb could not print the contents of the NSDictionary and could only tell me how many files there were elements，
As you can see from the console, the print method in the code is not affected.
enter image description here
and the e command also reported a generic error
enter image description here
But when the same object is returned to the OC file, the po command of lldb can print
out the content, and the e command will not report an error.
enter image description here
Then I created a new OC project, integrated all third-party libraries of the old project, and performed the same operation, and found that this problem did not occur.
enter image description here
Has anyone encountered the same problem? I hope someone can help solve it.

Post code and errors as text and avoid using homemade abbreviations.

Yes, po doesn't work in Swift. See What's the difference between "p" and "po" in Xcode's LLDB debugger?.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
